# Spark: what's the best strategy for joining a 2-tuple-key RDD with single-key RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two RDD's that I want to join and they look like this:

```
val rdd1:RDD[(T,U)]
val rdd2:RDD[((T,W), V)]
```

It happens to be the case that the key values of `rdd1` are unique and also that the tuple-key values of `rdd2` are unique.  I'd like to join the two data sets so that I get the following rdd:

```
val rdd_joined:RDD[((T,W), (U,V))]
```

What's the most efficient way to achieve this?  Here are a few ideas I've thought of.

Option 1:

```
val m = rdd1.collectAsMap
val rdd_joined = rdd2.map({case ((t,w), u) => ((t,w), u, m.get(t))})
```

Option 2:

```
val distinct_w = rdd2.map({case ((t,w), u) => w}).distinct
val rdd_joined = rdd1.cartesian(distinct_w).join(rdd2)
```

Option 1 will collect all of the data to master, right?  So that doesn't seem like a good option if rdd1 is large (it's relatively large in my case, although an order of magnitude smaller than rdd2).  Option 2 does an ugly distinct and cartesian product, which also seems very inefficient.  Another possibility that crossed my mind (but haven't tried yet) is to do option 1 and broadcast the map, although it would be better to broadcast in a "smart" way so that the keys of the map are co-located with the keys of `rdd2`.

Has anyone come across this sort of situation before?  I'd be happy to have your thoughts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

One option is to perform a broadcast join by collecting `rdd1` to the driver and broadcasting it to all mappers; done correctly, this will let us avoid an expensive shuffle of the large `rdd2` RDD:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "A"), (2, "B"), (3, "C")))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(((1, "Z"), 111), ((1, "ZZ"), 111), ((2, "Y"), 222), ((3, "X"), 333)))

val rdd1Broadcast = sc.broadcast(rdd1.collectAsMap())
val joined = rdd2.mapPartitions({ iter =>
  val m = rdd1Broadcast.value
  for {
    ((t, w), u) <- iter
    if m.contains(t)
  } yield ((t, w), (u, m.get(t).get))
}, preservesPartitioning = true)
```

The `preservesPartitioning = true` tells Spark that this map function doesn't modify the keys of `rdd2`; this will allow Spark to avoid re-partitioning `rdd2` for any subsequent operations that join based on the `(t, w)` key.

This broadcast could be inefficient since it involves a communications bottleneck at the driver.  In principle, it's possible to broadcast one RDD to another without involving the driver; I have a prototype of this that I'd like to generalize and add to Spark.

Another option is to re-map the keys of `rdd2` and use the Spark `join` method; this will involve a full shuffle of `rdd2` (and possibly `rdd1`):

```
rdd1.join(rdd2.map {
  case ((t, w), u) => (t, (w, u))
}).map {
  case (t, (v, (w, u))) => ((t, w), (u, v))
}.collect()
```

On my sample input, both of these methods produce the same result:

```
res1: Array[((Int, java.lang.String), (Int, java.lang.String))] = Array(((1,Z),(111,A)), ((1,ZZ),(111,A)), ((2,Y),(222,B)), ((3,X),(333,C)))
```

A third option would be to restructure `rdd2` so that `t` is its key, then perform the above join.

Comment: I think you're second option is probably the easiest way to go, though restructuring rdd2 would be convenient.

Comment: I'll have to learn more about the way the mapPartitions function works, but that seems like what I was looking for.  I also agree that I could re-structure `rdd2` and through a series of maps get back to the original thing I wanted.  I'll look into both options and see how well they perform for my use case.  Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: For the first option, when i try val rdd1Broadcast = sc.broadcast(rdd1.collectAsMap()) it returns data incomplete. Is there a way of adjusting first option using collect() instead of collecAsMap()?

Answer (score 15):

Another way to do it is to create a custom partitioner and then use zipPartitions to join your RDDs.

```
import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner

class RDD2Partitioner(partitions: Int) extends HashPartitioner(partitions) {

  override def getPartition(key: Any): Int = key match {
    case k: Tuple2[Int, String] => super.getPartition(k._1)
    case _ => super.getPartition(key)
  }

}

val numSplits = 8
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "A"), (2, "B"), (3, "C"))).partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(numSplits))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(((1, "Z"), 111), ((1, "ZZ"), 111), ((1, "AA"), 123), ((2, "Y"), 222), ((3, "X"), 333))).partitionBy(new RDD2Partitioner(numSplits))

val result = rdd2.zipPartitions(rdd1)(
  (iter2, iter1) => {
    val m = iter1.toMap
    for {
        ((t: Int, w), u) <- iter2
        if m.contains(t)
      } yield ((t, w), (u, m.get(t).get))
  }
).partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(numSplits))

result.glom.collect
```