# How to solve SPARK-5063 in nested map functions

Tags: java, nested, apache-spark

> RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

As the error says, i'm trying to map(transformation) a JavaRDD object within the main map function, how is it possible with Apache Spark?

The main JavaPairRDD object (TextFile and Word are defined classes):

```
JavaPairRDD<TextFile, JavaRDD<Word>> filesWithWords = new...
```

and map function:

```
filesWithWords.map(textFileJavaRDDTuple2 -> textFileJavaRDDTuple2._2().map(word -> new Word(word.getText(), (long) textFileJavaRDDTuple2._1().getText().split(word.getText()).length)));
```

also i tried foreach instead map function, but not working. (And of course searched SPARK-5063)

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815878/how-to-deal-with-error-spark-5063-in-spark

Answer (score 9):

In the same way nested operations on RDDs are not supported, nested RDD types are not possible in Spark. RDDs are only defined at the driver where, in combination with their `SparkContext` they can schedule operations on the data they represent.

So, the root cause we need to address in this case is the datatype:

```
JavaPairRDD<TextFile, JavaRDD<Word>> filesWithWords
```

Which in Spark will have no possible valid use.  Depending on the usecase, which is not further explained in the question, this type should become one of:

A collection of RDDs, with the text file they refer to:

```
Map<TextFile,RDD<Word>>
```

Or a collection of (textFile,Word) by text file:

```
JavaPairRDD<TextFile, Word>
```

Or a collection of words with their corresponding TextFile:

```
JavaPairRDD<TextFile, List<Word>>
```

Once the type is corrected, the issues with the nested RDD operations will be naturally solved.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. 
I tried to use Map like this:
Map<TextFile, JavaRDD<Word>> textMap = filesWithWords.collectAsMap();
textMap.forEach((textFile, wordJavaRDD) -> wordJavaRDD.map(word -> /* some transformation*/ ));
but again returns same error.

Comment: @Alp `collectAsMap()` will not give you back a `Map<TextFile, JavaRDD<Word>> `.  What are you trying to do btw? To me, it looks like the construction you're attempting is rather contrived.

Comment: `collectAsMap()` gives map (`java.util.Map`), i've checked it. I think you mean `scala.collection.Map`?
_TextFile_ class has _Path_ and _Text_ properties of any file,
_Word_ class has _word_ and its _count_ 
And i'm trying to count each word in current text file.
Also `JavaRDD<Word>` has all words that used in all text files not only current file, so i can't use simple wordCount examples

Comment: @Alp that is an extension of word count, counting  (file, word) pairs instead.

Comment: Why not?  Maybe you could post another question with the code you are trying. That approach should work,  so it's probably some issue related to your code.

Answer (score 3):

When I got to this exact same point in my learning curve for Spark (tried and failed to use nested RDDs) I switched to DataFrames and was able to accomplish the same thing using joins instead. Also, in general, DataFrames appear to be almost twice as fast as RDDs -- at least for the work I have been doing.

Answer (score 0):

@maasg
Firstly i used **JavaPairRDD< TextFile, JavaRDD < Word > >**, and it didn't work as you and @David Griffin said, it's not possible yet.
Models:

> TextFile(String path, String text)
>
> Word(String word, Integer count)

Now using **JavaRDD < TextFile >** and models have changed as:

> TextFile(String path, String text, List< Word > wordList)
>
> Word(String word, Integer count)

Finally,

```
List<Word> countDrafts = wordCount.map(v11 -> new Word(v11._1(), (long) 0)).collect();
JavaRDD<TextFile> ft = fileTexts.map(v11 -> new TextFile(v11._1(), v11._2(), countDrafts));
ft.foreach(textFile -> textFile.getWordList().forEach(word -> new  Word(word.getText(), getWordCountFromText(textFile.getText(), word.getText()))));
```

*getWordCountFromText()* function counts word in text of TextFile object, but not using spark reduce method unfortunately, using classic way.

By the way, i will try DataFrames in next days, but i have short time to do this.

Thank you all.

Comment: Instead of writing an answer to respond maasg's and David's answers, you might want to edit your post with the information above and delete this answer.

Comment: @MikelUrkia http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996427/how-to-solve-spark-5063-in-nested-map-functions/30029550?noredirect=1#comment48127506_30000494

Comment: What @maasg says is that you might want to write a new **question** - not an answer to your existing question - with the code you are trying, mainly because the *new* problem you have identified on his answer is not the same as the one posted in this question. That way it would be easier to give an answer to your *new* question.

Comment: it is not big deal or should not be.
just a clear answer to my question by me for devs who face with same problem

Comment: Maybe you are right, @Alp. You give an answer to your question, that is true. Just trying to help you out with your *new problem*. Cheers!