# How to replace RDD type of [String] with values of RDD type [String, Int]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Sorry for the confusion in the initial question. Here is a questions with the reproducible example:

I have an rdd of `[String]` and I have a rdd of `[String, Long]`. I would like to have an rdd of `[Long]` based on the match of `String` of second with `String` of first. Example:

```
//Create RDD
val textFile = sc.parallelize(Array("Spark can also be used for compute intensive tasks",
      "This code estimates pi by throwing darts at a circle"))
// tokenize, result: RDD[(String)]
val words = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
// create index of distinct words, result:  RDD[(String,Long)]
val indexWords = words.distinct().zipWithIndex()
```

As a result, I would like to have an RDD with indexes of words instead of words in `"Spark can also be used for compute intensive tasks"`.

Sorry again and thanks

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the map-function.

Comment: Since you can have many arrays inside each RDD then which pair of array will you use to get the result? or based on index?

Comment: @iboss The resulted rdd will be `values` of `y` based on the  matching `keys` with `x`.

Comment: I think you're confusing us all - should the Arrays in the example code actually be RDDs? In other words, is the first RDD of type `RDD[Array[String]]` or `RDD[String]`? If it's the latter and you're just "replacing" RDDs with Arrays for the example - please don't. If it's the former - please create a full example with RDDs with the expected results.

Comment: "paired rdd of `Array[String, Long]`" - still does not make sense. Is it an `RDD[(String, Long)]` (which can indeed be used as a PairRDD) or an `RDD[Array[(String, Long)]]`? If it's the latter, give a full example. If it's the former - why replace RDDs with Arrays in the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting an error of SPARK-5063 and given [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29819562/2455502), I found the solution to my problem:

```
//broadcast `indexWords`
val bcIndexWords = sc.broadcast(indexWords.collectAsMap)
// select `value` of `indexWords` given `key`
val result = textFile.map{arr => arr.split(" ").map(elem => bcIndexWords.value(elem))}
result.first()
res373: Array[Long] = Array(3, 7, 14, 6, 17, 15, 0, 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're interested in the indices of works that also appear in `Spark can also be used for compute intensive tasks`.

If so - here are two versions with identical outputs but different performance characteristics:

```
val lookupWords: Seq[String] = "Spark can also be used for compute intensive tasks".split(" ")

// option 1 - use join:
val lookupWordsRdd: RDD[(String, String)] = sc.parallelize(lookupWords).keyBy(w => w)
val result1: RDD[Long] = indexWords.join(lookupWordsRdd).map { case (key, (index, _)) => index }

// option 2 - assuming list of lookup words is short, you can use a non-distributed version of it
val result2: RDD[Long] = indexWords.collect { case (key, index) if lookupWords.contains(key) => index }
```

The first option creates a second RDD with the words whose indices we're interested in, uses `keyBy` to transform it into a PairRDD (with key == value!), `join`s it with your `indexWords` RDD and then maps to get the index only.

The second option should only be used if the list of "interesting words" is known not to be too large - so we can keep it as a list (and not `RDD`), and let Spark serialize it and send to workers for each task to use. We then use `collect(f: PartialFunction[T, U])` which applies this partial function to get a "filter" and a "map" at once - we only return a value if the words exists in the list, and if so - we return the index.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I applied option 1 to my data and got an rdd of this type:  `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Long]]`. My dataset  is an `RDD[String]` and consist of sentences so I use `map` to pass your code to each of the sentence. To make `join` I use `sc.parallelize(x)` inside of `map`.  At the end, I got a nested RDDs and I don't know how to get to a `String` type.

Comment: That won't work, you _cannot_ create `RDD[RDD[..]]`, and you cannot use a `SparkContext` inside an RDD transformation (e.g. `map`), don't even try that. I don't really get what you're trying to do (should each distinct word be mapped to its index in every sentence? What's the desired result type?) so I can't suggest an alternative, but usually whenever you think you need "nested RDDs" you actually should use `RDD.join` or `RDD.cartesian`.

Comment: Your right: I would like each word in a sentence to be mapped to its index in each sentence. The collection of indices is already done and you showed how to do the mapping in a single sentence. Now, I would like to apply it to an rdd via `map` transformation. The desired output is a `rdd[string]` with integers (instead of words) for each sentence.

Comment: Hi, could you update your answer to apply your solution to variable `textFile` from my example (i.e., on both initial sentences).