# Spark exception 5063 in TensorFlow extended example code on GPU

Tags: apache-spark, tensorflow, pyspark

I am trying to run an example code of TensorFlow extended at  https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/transform/census
on databricks GPU cluster.

My env:

```
7.1 ML Spark 3.0.0 Scala 2.12 GPU
python 3.7
tensorflow: Version: 2.1.1
tensorflow-transform==0.22.0
apache_beam==2.21.0
```

When I run

```
 transform_data(train, test, temp)
```

I got error:

```
 Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063
```

It seems that this is a known issue of RDD on Spark.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5063

I tried to search some solutions here, but none of them work for me.
[how to deal with error SPARK-5063 in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815878/how-to-deal-with-error-spark-5063-in-spark)

At the example code, I do not see where SparkContext is accessed from worker explicitly.
It is called from Apache Beam ?

Thanks

Comment: can you show the complete code please?

Comment: The complete code is at https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/transform/census