# Spark Runtime error when using saveAsTextFile

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run the following code using Spark in python:

```py
    def create_quantum_games(self, number_of_games):
        """
        Creates given number of quantum games 
        """
        current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
        file_path = self.base_file_path + current_datetime

        machines_rdd = self.sc.parallelize(range(10), 10)
        number_range = utils.get_number_list(self.precision)
        payoffs_rdd = machines_rdd.map(lambda _: self.payoffs_func(number_range))
        games_rdd = payoffs_rdd.map(lambda payoff: self.create_game(payoff, self.leaves))

        games_rdd.saveAsTextFile(file_path)

        self.sc.stop()
```

When running this code I always get the following runtime error:

> RuntimeError: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

However, if I comment out the line `games_rdd.saveAsTextFile(file_path)` there is no such error.

Am I using `saveAsTextFile` wrong? What I want to achieve is, that the contents of the `games_rdd` get saved to a text file (line by line).
Is there a better approach to achieve this?

Comment: This might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815878/how-to-deal-with-error-spark-5063-in-spark