# How do you perform basic joins of two RDD tables in Spark using Python?

Tags: python, join, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

How would you perform basic joins in Spark using python?  In R you could use merg() to do this.  What is the syntax using python on spark for:

1. Inner Join
2. Left Outer Join
3. Cross Join

With two tables (RDD) with a single column in each that has a common key.

```
RDD(1):(key,U)
RDD(2):(key,V)
```

I think an inner join is something like this:

```
rdd1.join(rdd2).map(case (key, u, v) => (key, ls ++ rs));
```

Is that right?  I have searched the internet and can't find a good example of joins.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It can be done either using `PairRDDFunctions` or Spark Data Frames. Since data frame operations benefit from [Catalyst Optimizer](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html) the second option is worth considering.

Assuming your data looks as follows:

```
rdd1 =  sc.parallelize([("foo", 1), ("bar", 2), ("baz", 3)])
rdd2 =  sc.parallelize([("foo", 4), ("bar", 5), ("bar", 6)])
```

#### With PairRDDs:

Inner join:

```
rdd1.join(rdd2)
```

Left outer join:

```
rdd1.leftOuterJoin(rdd2)
```

Cartesian product (doesn't require `RDD[(T, U)]`):

```
rdd1.cartesian(rdd2)
```

Broadcast join (doesn't require `RDD[(T, U)]`):

- see [Spark: what's the best strategy for joining a 2-tuple-key RDD with single-key RDD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17621596/1560062)

Finally there is `cogroup` which has no direct SQL equivalent but can be useful in some situations:

```
cogrouped = rdd1.cogroup(rdd2)

cogrouped.mapValues(lambda x: (list(x[0]), list(x[1]))).collect()
## [('foo', ([1], [4])), ('bar', ([2], [5, 6])), ('baz', ([3], []))]
```

#### With Spark Data Frames

You can use either SQL DSL or execute raw SQL using `sqlContext.sql`.

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd1, ('k', 'v1'))
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd2, ('k', 'v2'))

# Register temporary tables to be able to use `sparkSession.sql`
df1.createOrReplaceTempView('df1')
df2.createOrReplaceTempView('df2')
```

Inner join:

```
# inner is a default value so it could be omitted
df1.join(df2, df1.k == df2.k, how='inner') 
spark.sql('SELECT * FROM df1 JOIN df2 ON df1.k = df2.k')
```

Left outer join:

```
df1.join(df2, df1.k == df2.k, how='left_outer')
spark.sql('SELECT * FROM df1 LEFT OUTER JOIN df2 ON df1.k = df2.k')
```

Cross join (explicit cross join or configuration changes are required in Spark. 2.0 - [spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled for Spark 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38999140/1560062)):

```
df1.crossJoin(df2)
spark.sql('SELECT * FROM df1 CROSS JOIN df2')
```

```
df1.join(df2)
sqlContext.sql('SELECT * FROM df JOIN df2')
```

Since 1.6 (1.5 in Scala) each of these can be combined with `broadcast` function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast

df1.join(broadcast(df2), df1.k == df2.k)
```

to perform broadcast join. See also [Why my BroadcastHashJoin is slower than ShuffledHashJoin in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34139049/1560062)

Comment: just a note: cartesian is in fact available on RDD (not PairRDD)

Comment: df1.join(df2, df1.k == df2.k, joinType='left_outer') how do you multiple logic into the parameter input ? df1.k == df2.k | df1.k2 == df2.k2  ?

Comment: @paradox `(df1.k == df2.k) | (df1.k2 == df2.k2)` but it would make more sense to make it an `union` or melt and convert to equi-join.

Comment: @zero323: Excellent answer. the only change I recommend is that from version 2.0, they changed 'joinType' to 'how'.

Comment: Is it possible to add a function to the join condition. Say I have a function that checks the similarity of two strings and return an percentage of similarity. For example: `df1.join(df2, stringFunction(df1.k ,df2.k) > 80, how='left_outer')`