# Why my BroadcastHashJoin is slower than ShuffledHashJoin in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I execute a join using a `javaHiveContext` in Spark.

The big table is 1,76Gb and has 100 millions record.

The second table is 273Mb and has 10 millions record.

I get a `JavaSchemaRDD` and I call `count()` on it:

```
String query="select attribute7,count(*) from ft,dt where ft.chiavedt=dt.chiavedt group by attribute7";

JavaSchemaRDD rdd=sqlContext.sql(query);

System.out.println("count="+rdd.count());
```

If I force a `broadcastHashJoin (SET spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=290000000)` and use 5 executor on 5 node with 8 core and 20Gb of memory it is executed in 100 sec.
If i don't force broadcast it is executed in 30 sec.

N.B. the tables are stored as Parquet file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely the source of the problem is a cost of broadcasting. To make things simple lets assume that you have 1800MB in the larger RDD and 300MB in the smaller one. Assuming 5 executors and no previous partitioning a fifth of all data should be already on the correct machine. It lefts ~1700MB for shuffling in case of standard join.

For broadcast join the smaller RDD has to be transfered to all nodes. It means around 1500MB data to be transfered. If you add required communication with driver it means you have to move a comparable amount of data in a much more expensive way. A broadcasted data has to be collected first and only after that can be forwarded to all the workers.

Comment: So the broadcast comunication is more expensive if we consider the same mount of data?  In another test i have a big table with 1 billion record (17 Gb) and the little table is the same (270 Mb) and the broadcast join is faster than shuffledHashJoin...

Comment: Yes broadcasting is more expensive than shuffling since it requires communication through driver.  In  the second case amount of data which can stay in place in case of broadcast join is much larger compared to the amount of the broadcasted data hence you have more to gain.