# How to split a large data frame and use the smaller parts to do multiple broadcast joins in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Let's say we have two very large data frames - A and B. Now, I understand if I use same hash partitioner for both RDDs and then do the join, the keys will be co-located and the join might be faster with reduced shuffling (the only shuffling that will happen will be when the partitioner changes on A and B).

I wanted to try something different though - I want to try broadcast join like so -> let's say the B is smaller than A so we pick B to broadcast but B is still a very big dataframe. So, what we want to do is to make multiple data frames out of B and then send each as broadcast to be joined on A.

Has anyone tried this? 
To split one data frame into many I am only seeing randomSplit method but that doesn't look so great an option.

Any other better way to accomplish this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> Has anyone tried this?

Yes, someone already tried that. In particular GoDataDriven. You can find details below:

- presentation - https://databricks.com/session/working-skewed-data-iterative-broadcast
- code - https://github.com/godatadriven/iterative-broadcast-join

They claim pretty good results for skewed data, however there are three problems you have to consider doing this yourself:

- There is no split in Spark. You have to filter data multiple times or eagerly cache complete partitions ([How do I split an RDD into two or more RDDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32970709/9081732)) to imitate "splitting".
- Huge advantage of broadcast is reduction in the amount of transferred data. If data is large, then amount of data to be transferred can actually significantly increase: ([Why my BroadcastHashJoin is slower than ShuffledHashJoin in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34139049/9081732))
- Each "join" increases complexity of the execution plan and with long series of transformations things can get really slow on the driver side.

> randomSplit method but that doesn't look so great an option.

It is actually not a bad one.

> Any other better way to accomplish this task?

You may try to filter by partition id.

Comment: Did you tried iterative broadcast join? Or you have just copied the link here