# Join two RDD in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two rdd one rdd have just one column other have two columns to join the two RDD on key's I have add dummy value which is 0 , is there any other efficient way of doing this using join ?

```
val lines = sc.textFile("ml-100k/u.data")
val movienamesfile = sc.textFile("Cml-100k/u.item")

val moviesid = lines.map(x => x.split("\t")).map(x => (x(1),0))
val test = moviesid.map(x => x._1)
val movienames = movienamesfile.map(x => x.split("\\|")).map(x => (x(0),x(1)))
val shit = movienames.join(moviesid).distinct()
```

**Edit**:

Let me convert this question in SQL. Say for example I have `table1 (moveid)` and `table2 (movieid,moviename)`. In SQL we write something like:

```sql
select moviename, movieid, count(1)
from table2 inner join table table1 on table1.movieid=table2.moveid 
group by ....
```

here in SQL `table1` has only one column where as `table2` has two columns still the `join` works, same way in Spark can join on keys from both the RDD's.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you reformulate?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve filtering, like an inner join?

Comment: yes same as inner join dataset1=123,starwars ; dataset2=123; dataset1.join(datset2) fails because dataset2 is missing one element so I need to add default value in dataset2=123,0; then the join works is there a way if dataset2 contains less number of elements still the join works?

Comment: Can you give the types of your declared values?

Comment: I think [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621596/spark-whats-the-best-strategy-for-joining-a-2-tuple-key-rdd-with-single-key-rd?rq=1) has the answer that you're looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Join operation is defined only on `PairwiseRDDs` which are quite different from a relation / table in SQL. Each element of `PairwiseRDD` is a `Tuple2` where the first element is the `key` and the second is `value`. Both can contain complex objects as long as `key` provides a meaningful `hashCode`

If you want to think about this in a SQL-ish you can consider key as everything that goes to `ON` clause and `value` contains selected columns.

```
SELECT table1.value, table2.value
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.key = table2.key
```

While these approaches look similar at first glance and you can express one using another there is one fundamental difference. When you look at the SQL table and you ignore constraints all columns belong in the same class of objects, while `key` and `value` in the `PairwiseRDD` have a clear meaning.

Going back to your problem to use `join` you need both `key` and `value`. Arguably much cleaner than using `0` as a placeholder would be to use `null` singleton but there is really no way around it.

For small data you can use filter in a similar way to broadcast join:

```
val moviesidBD = sc.broadcast(
  lines.map(x => x.split("\t")).map(_.head).collect.toSet)

movienames.filter{case (id, _) => moviesidBD.value contains id}
```

but if you really want SQL-ish joins then you should simply use SparkSQL.

```
val movieIdsDf = lines
   .map(x => x.split("\t"))
   .map(a => Tuple1(a.head))
   .toDF("id")

val movienamesDf = movienames.toDF("id", "name")

// Add optional join type qualifier 
movienamesDf.join(movieIdsDf, movieIdsDf("id") <=> movienamesDf("id"))
```

Answer (score 0):

On RDD Join operation is only defined for PairwiseRDDs, So need to change the value to pairedRDD. Below is a sample

```
  val rdd1=sc.textFile("/data-001/part/")
  val rdd_1=rdd1.map(x=>x.split('|')).map(x=>(x(0),x(1)))
  val rdd2=sc.textFile("/data-001/partsupp/")
  val rdd_2=rdd2.map(x=>x.split('|')).map(x=>(x(0),x(1)))

  rdd_1.join(rdd_2).take(2).foreach(println)
```