# I have a query in Spark-Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have tried the following in spark-scala.

Logic:

If Code in Data1 = Code in Data2 the record has to be written to the output file. so based on this condition `4*2`; `8` rows are getting written.

Is there any way to optimize the below piece of code to group data?

```
.join(Data1,
 col("Code") === col("Code"), "inner")
 .selectExpr("Id" ,
            "Date",
            "Code"
             ).as[OutData]
```

```
Data1
+---------------+------------
|Id             |Code     
+---------------+------------
|0839           |06869242986
|4395           |06869242986
|3796           |06869242986
|3592           |06869242986
+---------------+------------

Data2
+---------------+------------
|Date           |Code     
+---------------+------------
|202050         |06869242986
|202051         |06869242986
+---------------+------------

OutData
+---------------+-------+------------
|Id             |Date   |Code
+---------------+-------+------------
|0839           |202050 |06869242986
|4395           |202050 |06869242986
|3796           |202050 |06869242986
|3592           |202050 |06869242986
|0839           |202051 |06869242986
|4395           |202051 |06869242986
|3796           |202051 |06869242986
|3592           |202051 |06869242986
+---------------+-------+------------
```

Comment: how can we use groupBy code along with join

Comment: have you tried the solution to this post? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33327239/7206701

Comment: you could use an broadcast join on the dataframe that has less records and that would eliminate the shuffle during the join operation. Also make sure that the dataframe with less records is not that big that would crash your driver node.