# Convert Array[(String,String)] type to RDD[(String,String)] type in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to spark.

Here is my code:

```
val Data = sc.parallelize(List(
      ("I", "India"), 
      ("U", "USA"), 
      ("W", "West"))) 

val DataArray = sc.broadcast(Data.collect)

val FinalData = DataArray.value
```

Here `FinalData` is of `Array[(String, String)]` type.
But I want data to be in the form of `RDD[(String, String)]` type.

Can I convert `FinalData` to `RDD[(String, String)]` type.

**More Detail:**

I want to join Two RDD So to optimize join condition(For performance point of view)
I am broadcasting small RDD to all cluster so that data shuffling will be less.(Indirectly performance will get improved)
So for all this I am writting something like this:

```
//Big Data
val FirstRDD = sc.parallelize(List(****Data of first table****))

//Small Data
val SecondRDD = sc.parallelize(List(****Data of Second table****))
```

So defintely I will broadcast Small Data set(means SecondRDD)

```
val DataArray = sc.broadcast(SecondRDD.collect)

val FinalData = DataArray.value
```

//Here it will give error that

```
val Join = FirstRDD.leftOuterJoin(FinalData)
```

> Found Array required RDD

That's why I am looking for Array to RDD conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadcasts are indeed useful to improve performance of a JOIN between a large RDD and a smaller one. When you do that, broadcast (along with `map` or `mapPartitions`) **replaces** the join, it's not used **in** a join, and therefore in no way you'll need to "*transform a broadcast into an RDD*".

Here's how it would look:

```
val largeRDD = sc.parallelize(List(
  ("I", "India"),
  ("U", "USA"),
  ("W", "West")))

val smallRDD = sc.parallelize(List(
  ("I", 34),
  ("U", 45)))

val smaller = sc.broadcast(smallRDD.collectAsMap())

// using "smaller.value" inside the function passed to RDD.map ->
// on executor side. Broadcast made sure it's copied to each executor (once!)
val joinResult = largeRDD.map { case (k, v) => (k, v, smaller.value.get(k)) }

joinResult.foreach(println)
// prints:
// (I,India,Some(34))
// (W,West,None)
// (U,USA,Some(45))
```

See a similar solution (using `mapPartitions`) which might be more efficient [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621596/spark-whats-the-best-strategy-for-joining-a-2-tuple-key-rdd-with-single-key-rd).

Answer (score 3):

The real is problem is that you are creating a `Broadcast` variable, by collecting the `RDD` (notice that this action converts the `RDD` into an `Array`). So, what I'm saying is that you already have an `RDD`, which is `Data`, and this variable has exactly the same values as `FinalData`, but in the form you want `RDD[(String, String)]`.

You can check this in the following output.

```
Data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[2] at parallelize at <console>:32
DataArray: org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast[Array[(String, String)]] = Broadcast(1)
FinalData: Array[(String, String)] = Array((I,India), (U,USA), (W,West))
```

Although, I don't understand your approach You just need to parallelize the `Broadcast`'s value.

```
// You already have this data stored in `Data`, so it's useless repeat this process.
val DataCopy = sc.parallelize(DataArray.value)
```

---

#### EDIT

After reading your question again, I believe the problem is almost the same. You are trying to `join` an `RDD` with a `Broadcast` and that's not allowed. However, if you read the documentation you may notice that it's possible to [join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions]) both `RDD`s (see code below).

```
val joinRDD = FirstRDD.keyBy(_._1).join(SecondRDD.keyBy(_._1))
```

Comment: But After broadcast I have to again convert FinalData to RDD. As FinalData is of Array type.

Comment: @Darshan perhaps you're not noticing the fact that `Data` has type `RDD[(String, String)]` - exactly what you seem to be looking for...

Comment: There is one function that i want to use. But that function is in RDD not in Array.That's why

Comment: @Tzach Zohar Yes `Data` has type `RDD[(String, String)]`

Comment: And what's the difference between `Data` and the RDD you're trying to create?

Comment: @Tzach Zohar But I want to use broadcast also. So after broadcast I will get variable as broadcasted type. I will get value of Broadcasted variable using `DataArray.value` And this will return as `Array` But i want it in `RDD`.So that future operation I can perform on `RDD`.

Comment: So you _intentionally_ want to shift the data back and forth 4 times between driver application and cluster nodes, just to end up with an _identical_ value?

Comment: Please check Newly add code. It will give brief idea about what I am looking for